# Collapse columns from long to wide format with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

How can I do what is being done below using data.table?

```
xy <- read.table(text = "Subject Product
1   ProdA
1   ProdB
1   ProdC
2   ProdB
2   ProdC
2   ProdD
3   ProdA
3   ProdB", header = TRUE)

aggregate(Product ~ Subject, FUN = paste, collapse = ";", data = xy)
```

Using dcast I get multiple columns with NA in some, but I need to collapse all columns for each subject using a "+" separator and removing the NA values.

```
dcast(xy, Subject ~ Product, value.var = "Product")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do a group by summarise instead of `dcast` with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(xy)[, .(Product = paste(Product, collapse=";")), by = Subject]
```

Comment: Excellent, I had no idea it would be possible to do it that way.

Comment: With `data.table`, the syntax is `dt[i, j, by]` .  We provide the row indexing/logical indexing etc in `i`, `by` for grouping and `j` for the summarisation of columns or creating new columns with `:=`