# Combine data by ID in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset where data from participants (ID) were collected multiple times. Is there a way to combine their data by ID if they have the same variables? I'm hoping to collapse the data to have one row per ID.

Looks something like this but I'm working with about 100+ variables:

```
id<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
age<-c(19,NA,NA,NA,52,NA,NA,22,NA,NA,36,NA,NA,NA)
values<-c(9,9,9,9,9,8,8,8,8,6,8,7,7,7)
acceptance<-c(8,8,7,6,9,7,5,8,8,5,8,7,6,5)
diffusion<-c(9,8,7,6,9,9,9,9,8,5,9,8,8,5)
attitudes<-c(7,7,6,6,9,7,7,8,8,8,9,6,3,3)
df<-data.frame(id,age,values,acceptance,diffusion,attitudes)

         id  age  values  acceptance  diffusion  attitudes

 1       1   19   9         8          9           7 
 2       1   NA   9         8          8           7
 3       1   NA   9         7          7           6
 4       1   NA   9         6          6           6
 5       2   52   9         9          9           9
 6       2   NA   8         7          9           7
 7       2   NA   8         5          9           7
 8       3   22   8         8          8           8
 9       3   NA   8         8          5           8
10       3   NA   6         5          9           8
11       4   36   8         8          9           9
12       4   NA   7         7          8           6
13       4   NA   7         7          8           3
14       4   NA   7         5          5           3
```

These scores (values, acceptance, etc.) were collected before and a few times after an intervention, but I'm hoping to collapse all of them under one ID if that's possible.

Desired output:

```
         id  age  values   acceptance  diffusion  attitudes

 1       1   19   9,9,9,9   8,8,7,6    9,8,7,6     7,7,6,6 
 2       2   52   9,8,8     9,7,5      9,9,9       9,7,7
 3       3   22   8,8,6     8,8,5      8,5,9       8,8,8
 4       4   36   8,7,7,7   8,7,7,5    9,8,8,5     9,6,3,3
```

I haven't come across a post with a similar issue and I'm not sure if it's possible to do so on R so any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Please show the expected output

Comment: You've got 4 rows with ID 1, each with different values for  `diffusion`. How do you want to combine them? Sum, mean, first value, last value, concatenate, .... ??

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should've been clearer. I edited the post and hopefully I make sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756372/collapse-text-by-group-in-data-frame

Comment: Or another duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59758011/collapse-columns-from-long-to-wide-format-with-data-table)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Collapse / concatenate / aggregate a column to a single comma separated string within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933958/collapse-concatenate-aggregate-a-column-to-a-single-comma-separated-string-w)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fill` the `NA` values in `age` and for each `id` and `age` collapse the values with `toString`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  fill(age) %>%
  group_by(id, age) %>%
  summarise(across(.fns = toString), .groups = 'drop')

#    id   age values     acceptance diffusion  attitudes 
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
#1     1    19 9, 9, 9, 9 8, 8, 7, 6 9, 8, 7, 6 7, 7, 6, 6
#2     2    52 9, 8, 8    9, 7, 5    9, 9, 9    9, 7, 7   
#3     3    22 8, 8, 6    8, 8, 5    9, 8, 5    8, 8, 8   
#4     4    36 8, 7, 7, 7 8, 7, 6, 5 9, 8, 8, 5 9, 6, 3, 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` grouping and summary methods to apply whatever collapsing/aggregation function you want.  You can even pass in a generic `f` and adjust as needed:

```r
library(dplyr)

f <- mean

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~f(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```